# More verbose Visual Studio template error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2012

In visual studio, I have oftentimes the following error:

```
Error   2   error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type. d:\w81.64\visual studio 2013\vc\include\xstddef 328 1   Test
```

With clang (and gcc I think), it used to print an error message like `"Info: in instanciation of"` then with the template that what instantiate, with what types and with the file name and line number of *where* the template was attempted to be *instantiated*, and recursively if the template is defined with another template.
I'd like to have the same info with MSVC, and I was wondering how I could achieve that.

Comment: Look in the Output window for the full message.

Comment: You could have put it in answer :).  However if you know how to transfer some of this information in the "Error List", feel free to write an answer.

Comment: That cannot work of course, the Error List window displays single-line error messages.  Template error messages require a book.

Comment: Some presentations in the GoingNative conferences point out that Clang has specific development efforts to giving better messages here, with some success.  There was also mention of using Clang as a back-end in VS, so you could use it for diagnostics even if not to generate useful code.  But for a cross-platform development, I just use whichever platform's message helps the most.

Comment: In qt creator with clang, it displays single-line error messages with a red mark in front of them, but it can (and actually often) display non-red-marked lines that complement information.  It's useful to have full error report and still be able to jump to it by clicking on the line number that failed to compile.